# Getting child entity as a type?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to dynamically create objects, and then call from them later. For example...

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    tabControl.TabPages.Add(i, i.ToString());
    richTextBox rtb = new richTextBox();
    rtb.Parent = tabControl.TabPages[i];
    rtb.dock = fill;
}
```

then later in my coding..

```
private void onButtonClick_example()
{
    var rtb = tabControl.SelectTab.GetChildrenByPoint(new point(1,1));
    rtb.WordWrap = true;
}
```

How can I return that child as a "rich text box" again?

Comment: `RichTextBox richText = rtb as RichTextBox;` Is that what you're going for? I'm not 100% sure what `GetChildrenByPoint` returns though; I'm assuming `Control` (though _Children_ implies `IEnumerable<Control>`--probably just semantics)?

Comment: Cast it? `(RichTextBox)tabControl.SelectTab.GetChildrenByPoint(new point(1,1));`

Comment: Wow, I didn't thinking casting it like that would work with a type like that. It worked. Thanks!

Comment: You can cast any type, as long as the cast is actually valid. Or use `as` to get a safer cast (if the cast doesn't work, `as` returns null instead of throwing an exception)

Comment: Using GetChildrenByPoint like that seems like a bit of a hack.  Is there any reason why you can't use tabControl.SelectedTab.Controls[0]?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to get the child. haha That might work better. Thanks stewartml!

Answer (score 1):

If GetChildrenByPoint returns something other than RichTextBox, then you need to use `as` and check for null so you don't crash when other controls are encountered.

```
foreach(var item in tabControl.SelectTab.GetChildrenByPoint(new point(1,1)))
{
  RichTextBox rtb= item as RichTextBox;
  if(rtb != null) //if we found a RichTextBox
  {
     rtb.WordWrap = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a dynamic ID to your rich text box control when you create it.
2. Loop through the controls in the selected tab:

   ```
   foreach(var control in tabControl.SelectTab.Controls)
   {
       if(control.ID == "NEWCONTROLID")
       {
         RichTextBox rtb = (RichTextBox) control;
       }
   }
   ```

Did this off the top of my head, so there may be code issues, but hopefully it puts you on the path.  Basically you need to search for the control you created in the controls collection of the selected tab, then cast it as a RichTextBox.

You could also use Control.Find() method to find your control and then cast it.